# Power from a small engine magneto

Tags: capacitor, resistors

I have a backpack mister (basically a leaf blower with a water tank) that is powered by a small 2 stroke gas engine. Another vendor sells an electrostatic charger which draws its electricity from the magneto of a small engine (one wire connects to the spark plug and the other connects to the engine chassis). However, when the device is connected, the motor on my mister cuts out. I assume that the current draw is too much for the small magneto (I think it was designed for a slightly larger motor).

My question is: is there a way to reduce the current draw from the magneto just enough to where the engine will continue to run? Could I install a resistor between the electrostatic device and the spark plug draw? Or would I want to consider a capacitor? If so, what voltage / uf range / etc would I want to use?

Sorry if the question sounds dumb, but I'd really like to get this thing working :-).

Comment: Have you looked into changing the magneto for a larger one?

Comment: Have you tried fiddling with (ie. reducing) the gap?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you face is that you need a 20..30kV resistor as this is the voltage the spark plug operates at. (Same with a capacitator, but don't even think about it.) These are hard-to-find parts which makes it expensive to meddle with it.

Comment: OK Thanks. The electrostatic charger was over $300, so I'm not worried about spending money on a resistor. What ohm rating would I use? Would the capacitor not work?

Comment: Most likely the cable of the charger is a resistor cable, giving the connection between the plug connector and the mesh some kΩ. Check this first. You could probably add up to 50% more resistance and check if this works. You haven't shortened the cable, have you? A capacitator wouldn't work as the power delivered by the inductor coil is still limited, and to be used by the spark plug. You buy an extremely expensive part there ($300 are nothing for a µF 30kV capacitator) which helps you electrocuting yourself, nothing more.

Comment: @Janka: I would think the best place to harvest energy would be in *series* with the spark plug.  A low-ESR cap with a voltage clamp shouldn't interfere with spark operation, but should be able to capture a significant portion of the magneto energy that would otherwise be wasted after the spark fires.